# configure JPDA in tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, centos, tomcat8, jpda

I have tomcat 8 on my centos server and the configuration of JPDA is (in catalina.sh):

```
export JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"
```

but after some minute of working with it (and connect to this port) the port was down with below error on catalina.out

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
Debugger failed to attach: recv failed during handshake: Resource temporarily unavailable
Debugger failed to attach: timeout during handshake
```

is it my configuration OK ?